# Export data as CSV with line breaks

Tags: c#, excel, csv

I'm trying to export data as a CSV file in C#, but the problems starts when i'm trying to import the csv file in excel.

In excel I'm using the function "import from text", and afterwards I set the delimiter to semicolon

My problem is that some of the columns have linebreaks and then the import in excel is wrong.

I have tried with single and doubles quotes with no luck.

I have searched for a solution, but has not found one yet.

Anyone knows if lumenworks has a export function, because i'm using this for the import function

The problem is the export function and the linebreaks are required.

```
if (list.Any())
                {
                    result = list.Select(i => new
                        {
                            i.Product.ProductIdentifier,
                            i.Product.Header,
                            body = string.Format("\"" + "{0}" + "\"", i.Product.Body),
                            Active = i.Product.Active ? 1 : 0,
                            Approved = i.Product.Approved ? 1 : 0,
                            i.Product.Sort,
                            i.Product.MetaDescription,
                            i.Product.MetaKeywords,
                            i.CatalogMenuItemContentItemId
                        }).ToList().ToCsv(";");
                }

string attachment = "attachment; filename=myfile.csv";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(result);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();    

public static string ToCsv<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, string seperator = ",")
        where T : class
    {
        var csvBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
        foreach (T item in items)
        {
            string line = string.Join(seperator, properties.Select(p => p.GetValue(item, null).ToCsvValue()).ToArray());
            csvBuilder.AppendLine(line);
        }
        return csvBuilder.ToString();
    }

    private static string ToCsvValue<T>(this T item)
    {
        return string.Format("{0}", HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(item.ToString()));
    }
```

Any idea ?

Comment: please post the code you tried so far.

Comment: so your problem is 'importing' or 'exporting' ?

Comment: I never use 3rd party for exporting data to csv file. I use always string.concat and add it to string array, then use File.WriteAllLines to write all data to file. Never had problem in excel. Without any codes or your csv file, it's impossible to find out where the problem is.

Comment: If you write the software yourself to export, maybe you can add a start and end char? That way when you import it in excel you can make a VBA software to look for start char, and if end char is not present on the same line -> grab the line below and make them one.

Comment: Do you need the line breaks in excel? If not, just remove them in code.